# GroupStyle with a WrapPanel without gaps

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

Using WPF's default implementation, is it possible to create GroupItems that use a WrapPanel without having the separation of GroupItems?

As an example, below you can see the obvious groupings. However, a new group will always be in "a new column". 
[image]

Here is the visual tree. It is obvious why this happens, but I am wondering if it is possible to create a panel that would support gapless/seamless wrapping so it doesn't feel like they are a separate list entirely.

[image]

One implementation I figure is possible would be to not group on the visual level but in the data level. It is already grouped in the CollectionViewSource, but I could do something in the ItemTemplate to visually group them. This feels a little hackish and only satisfies a very small number of edge cases. Thanks for reading!